# GRASS failed to initiate

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I've updated QGIS to 3.20 The following message is shown after loading the program.

> GRASS failed to initiate: GRASS not found in C:/PROGRA≈1/QGIS 3.20.0/apps/grass/grass78 (GISBASE), the provider and the complement will not work.

How can I fix this?